# Concat (##) the result of offsetof macro to an identifier?

Tags: c

I've been trying to use macro concatenation (##) with the **offsetof** macro to produce an identifier with no success:

```
CMain.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Color__builtin_offsetof'

struct Color_methods_TABLE
{
    struct
    {
        int8 getColor;
    }
    methods;
};

#define METHOD_NAME1(clazz, method) clazz##method
#define METHOD_NAME(clazz, method)  METHOD_NAME1(clazz, method)

#define tdef_name(clazz, method) METHOD_NAME(clazz, method)

int main()
{
    tdef_name(Color, offsetof(struct Color_methods_TABLE, methods.getColor));

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
Color0
```

Where 0 is the result of the offsetof macro. Can this be done? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do what you want. `offsetof` is (like `sizeof`) computed after preprocessing, during the compilation proper.

Look at the preprocessed form of your source code. With GCC you could get it using `gcc -C -E CMain.c > CMain.i` then use an editor (or a pager) to look inside `CMain.i` e.g. `less CMain.i`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.

To achieve your goal, C preprocessor needs to understand all the C built-in data type and types defined by programmer, that is **too much** for it.